# Manifest merge throwing error even with tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I am having problem while manifest merger even using `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"`

Note: I m posting only application tag here

my  main app Manifest is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="in.gobo"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <permission
        android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!--tools:replace="icon, label"-->
    <application
        android:name=".code.GoboApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

         >
```

and my module manifest if as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.payUMoney.sdk" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <!-- Create and manage accounts on device -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

   <!-- <permission
        android:name="com.payUMoney.sdk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.payUMoney.sdk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />-->

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- Extract device IEMI number -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <!-- Access Wifi State -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"
        />
    <!--tools:replace="android:icon"

    -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:icon="@drawable/green_app_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
        >
```

and ***while compiling  is its throwing error***
:

```
 Error:(43, 9) Attribute application@icon value=
 (@drawable/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:43:9 Error:(45, 9) 
 Attribute application@theme value=(@style/AppTheme) from 
 AndroidManifest.xml:45:9   is also present at gobo-user:PayUMoneySDK-
 Android:unspecified:67:9 value=(@style/MyTheme)    Suggestion: add 
 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <application> element at 
 AndroidManifest.xml:40:5 to override  Error:Execution failed for task 
 ':app:processDebugManifest'. Manifest merger failed with multiple 
 errors, see logs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` and `theme="@theme/MyTheme"` from your Application Manifest and replace drawable ic_launcher in PayU SDK with your app logo and that would do it.

Application will merge both manifest and you will get your desired theme and logo will be fetched from PayU's manifest hence you would have replaced their ic_launcher with yours